# python - save dict to .npy format

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `dict`and I associate an array to each key (the key itself is a number).

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
data = {}
data[2.5] = np.array([np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([5,6,7,8])])
```

Then I save the `dict`:

```
np.save('file.npy', data)
```

and then reload it:

```
datanew = np.load('file.npy')
```

--

Now, in order to access what is stored in each key, I **cannot** just do:

```
datanew[2.5]
```

But I have to do

```
datanew[()][2.5]
```

- Why?
- Is there a better way to save dicts?

Comment: Maybe a JSON file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is because [`np.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)'s `arr` argument expects an array. When you passed a dictionary it instead saved it as a one by one 'dimensionless' array. So when you load it, you need to get the 'first' element out of that dimensionless array (i.e. `[()]`). You could just do this when you call `np.load` though and then never worry about it again:

```
datanew = np.load('file.npy')[()]
```

Alternatively since you're trying to save a dictionary you could use pickle. `np.save` is suppose to be optimized for numerical arrays, I don't know if you still get the benefits it you've put your arrays in a dictionary though...

Comment: `np.save` uses `pickle` to save non-array objects, and conversely `pickle` uses the `save` format to save arrays.  So saving efficiency should be similar.